# Build failures with Mono 5.14.0.177, msbuild 15.0, nuget 4.7.1 on Travis CI, but not reproducible in VirtualBox

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, mono, nuget

I'm getting build failures with Mono 5.14.0.177, msbuild 15.0, nuget 4.7.1 on Travis CI for both Xenial and Trusty Ubuntu, but not reproducible in VirtualBox, Ubuntu Xenial.

After running:

`mono tools/nuget/nuget.exe restore pythonnet.sln -o packages`

the error message is:

```
Currently running NuGet.exe 4.1.0.
Updating NuGet.exe to 4.7.1.
Update successful.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from '/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'.
Error parsing solution file at /home/travis/build/pythonnet/pythonnet/pythonnet.sln: Invalid Image
```

Here is successful build in VirtualBox:

https://gist.github.com/denfromufa/23557331aba2ad548eba2fbff84f2307

And failing build in Travis CI:

https://travis-ci.org/pythonnet/pythonnet/jobs/419381040

More details in this issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/698

Comment: did any previous version of nuget work?

Comment: @knocte what are the correct flags to install specific version of nuget?

Comment: I didn't talk about flags; you could download e.g. 4.5.1 from `https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.5.1/nuget.exe` and test

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in pythonnet Travis CI temporarily by downgrading to msbuild 14.0:

```
cmd = "{0} update -self".format(nuget)
self.debug_print("Updating NuGet: {0}".format(cmd))
subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=use_shell)
cmd = "{0} restore pythonnet.sln  -MSBuildVersion 14 -o packages".format(nuget)
```

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/setup.py#L332